# Print large work on A4 printer

Tags: adobe-illustrator, print-design

I have a work I should adjust according to the uneven surface. I need to print the mockup on A4 printer, i.e. the result is the glued A4 pages where each of the page is a separate part of the image. In other words, I have no printer of sufficient size and want to joint separate A4 pages into one large paper.

I never performed such a task, thus I ask to provide Illustrator as well as printer side solutions.

Thanks

Comment: If you have access to InDesign, I'd advise you to place multiple instances of the large artwork on different A4 pages, print those and go wild with scissors and adhesives.

Comment: @bakabaka I have Ai only for now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also save your Illustrator document as a PDF, and just use Adobe Reader/Acrobat's (Reader shown below) **Poster** setting (red). After that you can adjust the options (yellow), and see a rough pagination preview of how the result would print (green).
If it isn't the default, set the A4 paper size in your printer properties. Reader/Acrobat will do the page tiling for you.
[image: Adobe Reader Poster Print]

Comment: that's cool answer! will check! up

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try and group your artwork into a single group, and then copy it as many times onto a new A4-sized artboard as you are planning on using pages. Mask the instances with a clipping mask so they fit the artboards, and then print them. Then you can go to town with scissors and your adhesive of choice.

Answer (score 0):

Open the required file in AI. Make sure that it is created on the artboard, which size corresponds to the final size of your printed work. Than start creating as many new artboards of A4 size as needed and place them under your whole file (of course remove the initial huge artboard). Check that all your image has artboards underneath, then save the file as PDF. That's it)